# after apache restart my file upload not working

Tags: php, apache, file-upload, centos, ping

I restarted my Apache server yesterday.
Previously my file upload was working.
But after apache server restart it throws some error.

```
 move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpYf1jox' to 'images/photo.jpg'
```

I gave the images folder permission to `777` and its Owner/Group is `apache apache`

I am using Centos. Meanwhile my

```
exec("ping -n 3 $ip", $output, $status);
```

is also not working. kindly help me.

Comment: Have you checked  your error logs?

Comment: yes. it throws warning: `move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpYf1jox' to 'images/photo.jpg'`

Comment: `move_uploaded_file(./images/photo.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Comment: is the folder writeable? and has permissions?

Comment: You have two questions here, one related to server management and one related to file upload. You need to separate the questions and tag appropriately.

Comment: Yes. I gave the images folder permission to `777` and its Owner/Group is `apache apache`. First i tried with `755` not worked then changed to `777` also not worked

Comment: @JayBlanchard the core problem occurs due to server restart. And I am finding the solution based on that.